# How to prevent a node from being deleted using Firebase Database rules?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase database, with only 3 main nodes. This is a chat app and below is the structure

```
chat_messages
    - chatID
        -messageID
            -message (string)
            -read (bool)
            -senderName (string)
            -senderProfilePic (string)
            -sent_by (string)(uid)
            -timestamp (string)
 
chat_room
    -chatID
        -chat_mode (string)
        -last_message (string)
        -timestamp (string)
        -members
            -uid (string)
                -email (string)
                -name (string)
                -photo (string)
                -uid (string)
                -userID (int)
                -userRole (string)

user_chatrooms
    -uid
        -chatID( string) : timestamp (string)
```

I set the basic security, allowing `read` and `write` to `true` and I received an email from firebase saying my database is having `insecure rules`

Then I re-configured the database rules as follows

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chat_messages":
    {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    },
    "chat_room":
    {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    },
    "user_chatrooms":
    {
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    }
    
  }
}
```

This provides an extra protection by blocking access to anything else outside the mentioned nodes.

now how can I prevent these nodes from being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a node from being deleted you can check whether new data is provided in write operations:

```
".write": "auth !== null && newData.exist()"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check. When we do this, will I stop getting the "unsecured database" emails? Also, can you please explain what's happening in your code? To me it's looks like you are checking whether the user is logged in and whether some data is provided by the user during the call, basically checking whether the data in the provided call is not null

Comment: If all you care about is stopping the emails, you can disable them by clicking on the bell icon in the top right of your Firebase console, and then on settings in the top right (next to "Alerts"). But I find it best to heed these warnings as they typically mean your database is open to abuse, for which you are responsible.

Comment: No, I'm interested in securing the data too, maybe I placed my question wrong, I wanted to check whetger my database will meet the minimum "secured database" standards of firebase. So my understanding about your code is right?

Comment: You asked "how can I prevent these nodes from being deleted?", which is what I answered here. Did you apply this change to your rules, and did that allow you to prevent the deletion?

Comment: Hey @PeakGen Any update on this? Did you get a chance to check whether this rule prevents deletion of the nodes as you asked?

Comment: Very sorry for the delay and thank you for checking back. Yes it did work. Thank  you 